# CFQuery not saving time portion to Oracle Datetime field

Tags: sql, oracle, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am having a problem using a datetime field in an Oracle database with Coldfusion with and don't know how to solve it.

I have a table (Subject) which contains a datetime field ("MODIFIED"). If I look the date I obtain *04-JAN-17* for instance. If I do this query:

`select to_char(MODIFIED, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from Subject`

It returns:

`04-01-2017 09:57:43`

I can retrieve this same result in ColdFusion.

I then try to copy that data to another table with the same structure if the "MODIFIED" value has changed. For doing that I retrieved the data in a first query and insert it into the new table. The data is retrieved correctly. Especially the date (I can see it in the ColdFusion script). However, the time of the date is lost. So for instance, I obtain *04-01-2017 **00:00:00*** instead of *04-01-2017 **09:57:43***.

Here is the relevant part of my script:

Main page:

```
<!-------- Get data -------->
<cfquery name="select_Subject_to_insert" datasource="#application.datasource#">
    SELECT CODE, MODIFIED, NAME FROM Subject 
</query>


<cfloop query="select_Subject_to_insert"> 
    <!-------- Create an object "Subject" -------->
    <cfscript>
        subject_to_insert = createObject("component", "Subject").init();
        subject_to_insert.id = -1;
        subject_to_insert.Code = select_Subject_to_insert.CODE;
        subject_to_insert.modified = select_Subject_to_insert.MODIFIED;
        subject_to_insert.name = select_Subject_to_insert.NAME;             
    </cfscript>
    <!-------- Call the function for saving data -------->
    saveSubject(subject_to_insert)
</cfloop>
```

Main component:

```
<!--- Function to save (update) Subject. --->
<cffunction name="saveSubject" returntype="string" access="remote">     
    <cfargument name="subject" required="yes" type="vo.Subject" />
    <cfset var timestp = createTimeStamp() />

    <!--- insert --->   
    <cfquery name="insertSubject" datasource="#application.datasource#" result="insertSubjectResult">
        insert into Subject (
            CODE,
            MODIFIED,
            NAME
            TIMESTAMP
        )values ( 
            <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.subject.CODE#" null="no" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"/>,                                                  
            <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.subject.MODIFIED#" null="no" cfsqltype="cf_sql_date"/>,                         
            <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.subject.NAME#" null="no" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"/>,                          
            <cfqueryparam value="#timestp#" null="no" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"/>                          
        )
    </cfquery>

    ........................................

</cffunction>
```

Could you please help me to understand why the time is not inserted correctly and solve the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use:

```
<cfqueryparam value="#arguments.subject.MODIFIED#" null="no" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp"/>
```

The `cf_sql_date` type does not have a time component whereas `cf_sql_timestamp` does. You can check the compatability matrix in [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html) to see that `cf_sql_timestamp` corresponds to the Oracle `DATE` data type.

You can also simplify your page to get rid of the function call (assuming it is not doing extra processing):

```
<cfquery name="insertSubject" datasource="#application.datasource#" result="insertSubjectResult">
  insert into Subject (
    CODE,
    MODIFIED,
    NAME
    TIMESTAMP
  )
  SELECT code,
         modified,
         name,
         <cfqueryparam value=createTimeStamp() null="no" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"/>
  FROM   subject
  -- WHERE some_condition
</cfquery>
```

Comment: The problem doesn't come of timestamp (last field), If I delete the field of the database and in the queries it will be the same problem. It's the field MODFIED (datafield) the real problem.

Comment: @coeurdange57 Please re-examine the first part of my answer - you need to use the `cf_sql_timestamp` type when passing the value into the query parameter for the `MODIFIED` column.

Comment: Ok but I have to put the old modified value in the field MODIFIED of the new table and not a timestamp. How can I to do that?

Comment: @coeurdange57 Have you tried replacing `cf_sql_date` with `cf_sql_timestamp`? That should be the only change that is needed in your code.

Comment: `CF_SQL_DATE` is analogous to an ANSI date literal while `CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP` is to an ANSI timestamp literal. So even though an Oracle `DATE` can store time as well as the date (although to a lower precision than the Oracle `TIMESTAMP`), you'll need to use `CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP` to preserve the time portion for an Oracle `DATE` (or, for that matter, a SQL Server `datetime`).